# InflateException Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, material-design

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.atech.a_business, PID: 30662
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.atech.a_business/com.atech.a_business.layout.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3124)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3233)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6873)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
>                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:904)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>                         at com.atech.a_business.layout.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:69)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3077)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3233) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6873) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
>                      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:904) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>                         at com.atech.a_business.layout.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:69) 
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550) 
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3077) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3233) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6873) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
>                      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
>                         at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:36)
>                         at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.(CoordinatorLayout.java:192)
>                         at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.(CoordinatorLayout.java:186)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:904) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>                         at com.atech.a_business.layout.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:69) 
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550) 
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3077) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3233) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6873) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

CoordinatorLayout xml file:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"></FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Main Activity .xml**

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**the main activity class**

```
package com.atech.a_business.layout;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.atech.a_business.R;
import com.atech.a_business.layout.fragments.HomeFragment;
import com.atech.a_business.layout.fragments.MoviesFragment;
import com.atech.a_business.layout.fragments.NotificationsFragment;
import com.atech.a_business.layout.fragments.PhotosFragment;
import com.atech.a_business.layout.fragments.SettingsFragment;
import com.atech.a_business.layout.settings.AboutUsActivity;
import com.atech.a_business.util.CircleTransform;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawer;
private View navHeader;
private ImageView imgNavHeaderBg, imgProfile;
private TextView txtName, txtWebsite;
private Toolbar toolbar;
//private FloatingActionButton fab;

// urls to load navigation header background image
// and profile image
private static final String urlNavHeaderBg = "http://api.androidhive.info/images/nav-menu-header-bg.jpg";
private static final String urlProfileImg = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/eCtE_G34M9ygdkmOpYvCag1vBARCmZwnVS6rS5t4JLzJ6QgQSBquM0nuTsCpLhYbKljoyS-txg";

// index to identify current nav menu item
public static int navItemIndex = 0;

// tags used to attach the fragments
private static final String TAG_HOME = "home";
private static final String TAG_PHOTOS = "photos";
private static final String TAG_MOVIES = "movies";
private static final String TAG_NOTIFICATIONS = "notifications";
private static final String TAG_SETTINGS = "settings";
public static String CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;

// toolbar titles respected to selected nav menu item
private String[] activityTitles;

// flag to load home fragment when user presses back key
private boolean shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress = true;
private Handler mHandler;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mHandler = new Handler();

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    //fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    // Navigation view header
    navHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    txtName = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.name);
    txtWebsite = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.website);
    imgNavHeaderBg = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_header_bg);
    imgProfile = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_profile);

    // load toolbar titles from string resources
    activityTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_item_activity_titles);

    /*fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });*/

    // load nav menu header data
    loadNavHeader();

    // initializing navigation menu
    setUpNavigationView();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        navItemIndex = 0;
        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
        loadHomeFragment();
    }
}

/***
 * Load navigation menu header information
 * like background image, profile image
 * name, website, notifications action view (dot)
 */
private void loadNavHeader() {
    // name, website
    txtName.setText("Ravi Tamada");
    txtWebsite.setText("www.androidhive.info");

    // loading header background image
    Glide.with(this).load(urlNavHeaderBg)
            .crossFade()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(imgNavHeaderBg);

    // Loading profile image
    Glide.with(this).load(urlProfileImg)
            .crossFade()
            .thumbnail(0.5f)
            .bitmapTransform(new CircleTransform(this))
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(imgProfile);

    // showing dot next to notifications label
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(3).setActionView(R.layout.menu_dot);
}

/***
 * Returns respected fragment that user
 * selected from navigation menu
 */
private void loadHomeFragment() {
    // selecting appropriate nav menu item
    selectNavMenu();

    // set toolbar title
    setToolbarTitle();

    // if user select the current navigation menu again, don't do anything
    // just close the navigation drawer
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CURRENT_TAG) != null) {
        drawer.closeDrawers();

        // show or hide the fab button
        //toggleFab();
        return;
    }

    // Sometimes, when fragment has huge data, screen seems hanging
    // when switching between navigation menus
    // So using runnable, the fragment is loaded with cross fade effect
    // This effect can be seen in GMail app
    Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            Fragment fragment = getHomeFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                    android.R.anim.fade_out);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    };

    // If mPendingRunnable is not null, then add to the message queue
    if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
        mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
    }



    //Closing drawer on item click
    drawer.closeDrawers();

    // refresh toolbar menu
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

private Fragment getHomeFragment() {
    switch (navItemIndex) {
        case 0:
            // home
            HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
            return homeFragment;
        case 1:
            // photos
            PhotosFragment photosFragment = new PhotosFragment();
            return photosFragment;
        case 2:
            // movies fragment
            MoviesFragment moviesFragment = new MoviesFragment();
            return moviesFragment;
        case 3:
            // notifications fragment
            NotificationsFragment notificationsFragment = new NotificationsFragment();
            return notificationsFragment;

        case 4:
            // settings fragment
            SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
            return settingsFragment;
        default:
            return new HomeFragment();
    }
}

private void setToolbarTitle() {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(activityTitles[navItemIndex]);
}

private void selectNavMenu() {
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(navItemIndex).setChecked(true);
}

private void setUpNavigationView() {
    //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

            //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                case R.id.home:
                    navItemIndex = 0;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_photos:
                    navItemIndex = 1;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_PHOTOS;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_movies:
                    navItemIndex = 2;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_MOVIES;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_notifications:
                    navItemIndex = 3;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_NOTIFICATIONS;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_settings:
                    navItemIndex = 4;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_SETTINGS;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_about_us:
                    // launch new intent instead of loading fragment
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutUsActivity.class));
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
                    return true;

                default:
                    navItemIndex = 0;
            }

            //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
            if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                menuItem.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
            }
            menuItem.setChecked(true);

            loadHomeFragment();

            return true;
        }
    });


    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
    drawer.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    //calling sync state is necessary or else your hamburger icon wont show up
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        return;
    }

    // This code loads home fragment when back key is pressed
    // when user is in other fragment than home
    if (shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress) {
        // checking if user is on other navigation menu
        // rather than home
        if (navItemIndex != 0) {
            navItemIndex = 0;
            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
            loadHomeFragment();
            return;
        }
    }

    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    // show menu only when home fragment is selected
    if (navItemIndex == 0) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    }

    // when fragment is notifications, load the menu created for notifications
    if (navItemIndex == 3) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.notifications, menu);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logout user!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

    // user is in notifications fragment
    // and selected 'Mark all as Read'
    if (id == R.id.action_mark_all_read) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All notifications marked as read!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // user is in notifications fragment
    // and selected 'Clear All'
    if (id == R.id.action_clear_notifications) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clear all notifications!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

Comment: Is this the whole file? You do not have an end tag for `CoordinatorLayout`. ( `</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>` )

Comment: this link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571097/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-coordinatorlayout

Comment: sure i have ! i'have any syntaxe error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution and it's to create the following theme in your styles-v21.xml (it should already be there if you imported the sample files, but if it is not there, please create it):

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

And calling it in the manifest, in the main activity part, as follows (delete the line I highlighted earlier and put this in its place):

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

this should solve the probleme.

for more explications: https://github.com/Marketcloud/marketcloud-sample-android-application/issues/1

Answer (score 0):

Use AppCompatActivity instead of Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you must use AppCompatActivity (from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html): "Base class for activities that use the support library action bar features".) instead of Acivity.

Comment: i'm using appcompat in the main activity i'll share it.